# How to remove section header when moving last row from a section

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data

I have an UITableView that is connected to core data. The tableview has dynamic cells and groups the rows into sections (categories).

I can move the rows by dragging between the sections and this works fine with core data except when I the drag a row and the section becomes empty. I would like the section header to disappear but it stays as a header with no rows inside. Then if I try to drag a row back I get an error.

I have implemented the NSFetchedResultsController functions for didChangeObject and didChangeSection. However when dragging the rows I figured out that I have to set the delegate for fetchedResultsController to nil.

Here is the part of the code that handles move.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

  // Create array of fetched  items from the stack
  var items = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects! as! [Item]

  // Convert the index paths to row number in the table.
  let destinationRow = rowAtIndexPath(destinationIndexPath)
  var sourceRow = rowAtIndexPath(sourceIndexPath)

  // Source row has to be reduced by one if it was moved to lower section because tableview is counting the row twice, once in the new section and once as the row index in the old section.
  if sourceIndexPath.section > destinationIndexPath.section {
    sourceRow -= 1
  }

  let newCategory = fetchedResultsController.sections![destinationIndexPath.section].name

  // Get the  item of from the source index path and update the category
  let item = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(sourceIndexPath) as! Item
  item.category = newCategory

  // Do not trigger delegate methods when changes are made to core data
  fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil

  // Move the  item in core data
  items.removeAtIndex(sourceRow)
  items.insert(item, atIndex: destinationRow)


  do {
    try coreDataStack.context.save()
  } catch {
    fatalCoreDataError(error)
  }

  fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
}
```

I have not found any question that answers this, especially not in Swift.
Any help to solve this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to set the `delegate` to `nil`?  If this is because of an error that would indicate you have implemented something incorrectly.

Answering your original question: Since you are using an `NSFetchedResultsController` then the section will be removed automatically by the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` method `controller(_, didChangeSection, atIndex, forChangeType)`

The real question is, why did you set the `delegate` to `nil`?

Comment: I set the delegate to nil because I'm changing the tableview by dragging rows. In this case I don't want the NSFetchedResultsController to trigger the method controller(_, didChangeObject, atIndex, forChangeType) as the move has already been done in the tableview. I tried keeping the delegate active but for some reason it does not trigger the method controller(_, didChangeSection, atIndex, forChangeType). What action would trigger this method?

Comment: Even when you are dragging rows you still want to use the `NSFetchedResultsController`'s methods.  You don't move the rows, you change the underlying data that would cause the row to get moved to the new position and then let the `NSFetchedResultsController` do its job.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! I will try to get my head around this. Any suggestions where to find some good sample code would be appreciated. I see you have some interesting presentations on youtube:)

Comment: Implement the code that is in the documentation for the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`.  When you move a row you just adjust the value that will cause the row to be sorted into the new location in the `NSManagedObject`.  That is all you need to do.  There is no sample code that will do that second step for you since that is dependent on your code base.

Comment: Thanks! I now managed to trigger the controller(_, didChangeSection, atIndex, forChangeType) and the section header disappears when there are no more rows. This has however led to other questions on the UITableView behavior but I will open a new question for that.